# Populating ArcMap column with inputs from other colum, shortening original text?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I need to keep the first part of all inputs and get rid of the last part, so that i can later make a join based on the new attribute.

Edit: found solution by using simple python script `!MY_FIELD![:-9]`, which put in field calculator removed the last 9 characters.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  To find similar Q&As here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop+python-parser+field-calculator?sort=frequent&pageSize=50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or if you don't use python, you can use calculate field:

```vbs
NewField = Left([FromField], 1)
```

Where:

- `NewField` = Fields which will contains new data
- `FromField` = Fields which contain original data
- `1` = specified number of characters from the left side of the starting line

More information can be found at [ArcGIS Desktop Calculate Field Examples](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm)